# symfony2 rendering of a form as form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have two entities Invoice and Customer. I also have two forms InvoiceForm and CustomerForm.
When I create a new Invoice (with InvoiceForm), I want to be able to also create a new Customer (just one). So here is how I do it (and it works):

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class CustomerForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('phone');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'customer_create';
    }
}

<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class InvoiceForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('date')
            ->add('customer', new CustomerForm());
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'invoice_create';
    }
}
```

So in my view (Invoice/new.html.twig) I can easily customize the way I display the attributes of my InvoiceForm (title and date), I mean I can put my form_row(invoiceForm.title) in whatever  I want, I really can do anything. But for the attributes of my "subform" invoiceForm.customer, I can't, it's done automatically (firstname, lastname, phone) because all I can do is use invoiceForm.customer. Do you see what I mean?

If, in my Controller, I was making a "new CustomerForm()", and then rendering this form, I could do what I want, but since I'm making a "new InvoiceForm()", I can't. I don't know if I explain correctly ^^

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This seems a bit backwards.  There should be a OneToMany relationship from Customer to Invoice.  Then from a new customer one could nest an invoice form.  For existing customers, create an invoice after selecting the customer.

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing all this: I have a separated page with my CustomerForm only, (/customer/new), and from my customer view, I can create a new invoice. But the customer (not the entity ^^) wants also to be able to create a new customer (the entity) from the invoice create view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've found the answer by myself, actually I can access my subform attributes with:

```
{{ form_row(form.customer.firstname }}
{{ form_row(form.customer.lastname }}
{{ form_row(form.customer.phone }}
```

So I can customize as I need. And also, there is a way to test the form type in the view:

```
{{ form.customer.vars.block_prefixes.2 }}
```

which in my case will return *customer_create* as the name of my subform (yeah I know I did not ask for that, but I needed it too ^^ so maybe it will help someone else ;) )

Thank you!